# foreach loop not creating multi-dimensional array

Tags: powershell

I have a function that gets a list of databases and allows the user to select which ones they want to use, the array needs to be made into a multi-dimensional array because I need a file path against the database name.

Here is the code:

```
function GetDBList {
    Param ($MoveAll)
    $ServerAddress = "."
    $DBList = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT name FROM   sys.databases WHERE  CASE WHEN state_desc = 'ONLINE'  THEN OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(name) + '.[dbo].[settings]', 'U') END IS NOT NULL" -ServerInstance $ServerAddress

    $databaseList = @()
    $databaseListDoc = @()
    $databaseListSelect = @()
    $databaseListFinal = @()

    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $dbList.count; $i++) {
        $databaseList += $dbList.ItemArray[$i]
    }

    # ----------------- EDIT ------------------------------------------------------
    # Gets the document path - Needs to be changed to account for multiple branches
    $i = 0

    # Beging database selection ----------------------
    if ($MoveAll -eq $false) {

    # Form creation removed 

        foreach ($item in $databaseList) {
            [void]$listBox.Items.Add($item)
        }

    # Form creation removed 

        if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK) {
            $databaseListSelect += $listBox.SelectedItems
        }

        foreach ($item in $databaseListSelect) {
            $DBPath = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT TOP 1 BDocumentsFolder FROM tblBranchSettings" -ServerInstance $ServerAddress -Database $item
            $path = $DBPath.ItemArray[0] -replace ('\Documents', "")

            $databaseListFinal += ,@($item, $path)
            $i++
        }
    } else {
        foreach ($item in $databaseList) {
            $DBPath = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT TOP 1 BDocumentsFolder FROM tblBranchSettings" -ServerInstance $ServerAddress -Database $item
            $path = $DBPath.ItemArray[0] -replace ('\Documents', "")

            $databaseListFinal += ,@($item, $path)
            $i++
        }
    }

    return , $databaseListFinal
}
```

The `foreach` loop in the `else` block at the bottom works fine, when I print it out after the function call I get both the database name and the file path. The one inside the `if` block (at the end of the `if` block) does not, it only prints out the name of the database.

Comment: way too much code in there! have a read of this article and strip your answer back to its basics, please! https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Does the query insde that loop actually return a result? What's the value of `$DBPath`. As a side note: creating a list of custom objects generally is a better approach than creating a list of arrays.

Comment: It seems to be an issue with server 2008 and the query, if I run the query in SQL Server it works fine, but it seems if I have any more than one clause in the query, PowerShell doesn't pick it up. I have fixed it up by looking at the database name but this isn't ideal since id rather have just the databases that are relevant rather than all of them.